# Changing the Collation of database column is not working in laravel migrations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to change the collation of the column "`about_me`" from "`users`" table. For that, I am using below code. I am simply changing the collation to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` but the code is not working.

```
 public function up()
    {
        if (Schema::hasColumn("users", "about_me")) {
            Schema::table("users", function(Blueprint $table) {
                $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
                $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            });
        }
 }
```

I already changed in /config/database.php, this helped me to save the data in db but after fetching the database, I found the special symbols are not displaying, when I changed the Collation of that column to utf8mb4_unicode_ci then it worked fine. But I want to make it in migration. The current code is not working, I need the correct code which works well.

Comment: Laravel supports modify collation per column basis for MySQL. You need to write a raw query here to do a table-wide modification

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Laravel supports modifying collation per column basis for MySQL. For a table wide modification, you need to write a raw query.

```
public function up()
{

    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE users CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci");
}
```

Comment: Gives error: Cannot access protected property $table. But it works nice with {$table->table} => users. Also, Schema::table is useless here, you can write directly DB::statement(...)

Comment: Thanks for the review @ManicDepression. Answer has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

In modern Laravel there are charset and collations that can be set on table or columns.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#database-connection-table-options

```
    // You can change table.
    Schema::table('users`', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
        $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
    });

    // You can change on a field of a table.
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('about_me')->charset('utf8mb4')->collation('utf8mb4_unicode_ci')->change();
    });
```